# Managing sys.path for multiple developers

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sys.path

The problem I'm facing is small but annoying:

A colleague is working on one project in version control system X (VCS-X). 
Another colleague is working in another version control system Y and uses the packages from X.

Unfortunately colleague in VCS-X uses local import and modifies his path using `sys.path.append('trunk/my_location')` in their code.

My view is that this is wrong practice as colleagues in X forces colleague Y to edit the code prior to being able to run it, merely because their repo is named differently.

How should these dependencies be managed?

#### Example:

**Developer X**:

```
>>> sys.path.append('my_repo/my_location')
>>> from my_location import toolbox
>>> nosetests -v
toolbox.test1 ... ok
toolbox.test2 ... ok
...
```

**Developer Y**:

Step 1:

```
>>> nosetests -v
toolbox.test1 ... fail
...
```

Step 2:

```
>>> sys.path.append('my_repo/my_location')
>>> from my_location import toolbox
Import error: No such package.
```

Step 3:

```
>>> sys.path.append('my_colleagues_repo/my_location')
>>> from my_location import toolbox
>>> nosetests -v
toolbox.test1 ... ok
toolbox.test2 ... ok
```

"...Sigh follows; the code is working ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nobody** should be doing `sys.path.append`!  This is a workflow problem that you should address first and foremost.

In this situation it will be appropriate to package the `toolbox` into a distribution.  The developer who just wants to *use* the code from `toolbox`, i.e. via an import statement or command line script, will execute:

```
pip install --user toolbox
```

The developer who wants to work *on* the `toolbox` code should also be using pip install.  However, this developer should clone the repo, create/activate a virtual environment, and execute:

```
 pip install --editable .
```

In both situations, pip will sort out the necessary `sys.path` stuff for you in the correct way.

Follow the [PyPA Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) for the details on how to create a distribution.